# How to change fill color for SVG as background-image?

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I have a SVG as Background Image in a div. When I add a class "svg" via JQuery I would like to change the fill color of this SVG.

How can I do that?

Here is my Code so far:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="sg_lines"></div>

<!-- JS -->
$('.glyphs').on('click', function(e){
    $('#sg_lines').addClass('svg');
});

<!-- CSS -->
#sg_lines {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 299;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 1320px;
 height: 1080px;
 background-image: url('../../images/lines_foreground.png');
}

#sg_lines.svg img {
 fill: red;
}
```

Thanks

kay899

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a `.png` as background-image though.

Also, I'm afraid that when you have a `svg` as the src of an `<img>` tag or as `background-image` you can't programatically change its properties such as fill.

You need to somehow refactor your code so it uses an **inline svg** (that is, the actual svg markup right there among your html markup). That way you can use CSS to alter its properties.

Comment: So, there is really no way to use it like my setup?